Precison of InterpolatingFunction decreases to MachinePrecision in ParallelTable
Bug introduced after 8.0.4, persisting through 14.1.

Here is the code:
ff = SetPrecision[
   Interpolation[{{1, Complex[1.2, 2.5]}, {2, Complex[4.2, 3.5]}, {3, 
      Complex[3.2, 3.5]}, {4, Complex[4.2, 3.5]}}], 100];
Table[Precision[ff[i]], {i, 2}]
ParallelTable[Precision[ff[i]], {i, 2}]
(*{98.9294, 99.9627}*)
(*{MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}*)

The problem is that the results from ParallelTable do not maintain the precision I set beforehand. Is there anyone who can help me figure it out? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Please read comments under Precision loss when assigning to the elements of a list interpolation function during ParallelDo, which is about the very same problem than yours.

@Domen Thanks for the comment!

When we define something in the main kernel, like an interpolating function, we have to serialize it in order to send the definition to a parallel kernel before it can be used on that kernel.
But when we serialize an InterpolatingFunction it seems to forget the fact that its output should have a certain precition:
In[10]:= 
interp1 = 
  SetPrecision[
   Interpolation[{{1, Complex[1.2, 2.5]}, {2, Complex[4.2, 3.5]}, {3, 
      Complex[3.2, 3.5]}, {4, Complex[4.2, 3.5]}}], 100];
interp2 = ToExpression[ToString[interp1, InputForm]];
Table[Precision[interp1[i]], {i, 2}]
Table[Precision[interp2[i]], {i, 2}]

Out[12]= {98.9294, 99.9627}

Out[13]= {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}

So this issue isn't really about ParallelTable but more that whatever internal flag is set on the InterpolatingFunction regarding its output precision is not serialized.  That seems like a bug to me.
To work around it here, we can skip the serialization altogether and define the interpolating function directly in the parallel kernels:
In[7]:= ParallelEvaluate[
  ff = SetPrecision[
    Interpolation[{{1, Complex[1.2, 2.5]}, {2, Complex[4.2, 3.5]}, {3,
        Complex[3.2, 3.5]}, {4, Complex[4.2, 3.5]}}], 100]];

In[8]:= ParallelTable[Precision[ff[i]], {i, 2}]

Out[8]= {98.9294, 99.9627}


Side note: the bug is introduced after 8.0.4: https://i.sstatic.net/yrEdYB30.png
